# Assign array into php string

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [counterPickTime] => January [courierRetTime] => [Courier] => S [CourierRet] =>
[counterPick] => [orderType] => Merchant [destination] => interDistrict [creation_date] => 2021-04-19
22:28:44 [PreRet] => [PreRetTime] => [reason] => [reasonEnglish] => [PickDropBy] => tuntun45 )
```

I want to assign all array names as php strings with their values. Example: `[counterPickTime] => January` I want `$counterPickTime= "January";` in php! How can I do that?

Tried with -

```
implode(',', $result)

json_encode($result)
```

but nothing worked for it's complex pattern, how to do that? :(

Comment: Might I ask why you think you need separate variables? What's wrong with just accessing the values straight from the array? And if you want to encode it into JSON, then just supply the whole array. Turning it into a string before turning it into JSON makes no sense.

Comment: Are you trying to re-create https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php …?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    ${$k} = $v;
}
```

Comment: Hello, you should add details to your answer explaining what it does and why. So OP and next readers can understand it directly

Comment: Aside from lacking explanation, this is basically what `extract`, a built-in PHP function does, so there would be no real need to implement this on your own.